# Vehicle wheels sink in floor - Scenekit(IOS)

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm making a car in scenekit and the wheels seem to sink in the floor.
I used Apples code to make it. When I use their model it works fine. **But** when I use mine it does not. I can't figure out why thats happening. Heres a picture of the car wheels sinking and the code is right below it.[image] [image]

```
@IBAction func AddFloor(_ sender: Any) {
    let floor = SCNNode()
    let floorGeom = SCNFloor()
    floorGeom.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = "concrete.png"

    floor.geometry = floorGeom
    let staticBody = SCNPhysicsBody.static()
    floor.physicsBody = staticBody

    floor.position = SCNVector3(0, -10, 0)

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floor)
}


@IBAction func AddCar(_ sender: Any) {
    let chassisNode = getNode("rccarBody", fromDaePath: "Models.scnassets/rc_car.scn")
    let wheelnode0 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelFrontL", recursively: false)
    let wheelnode1 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelFrontR1", recursively: false)
    let wheelnode2 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelRearL", recursively: false)
    let wheelnode3 = chassisNode
        .childNode(withName: "wheelRearR", recursively: false)


    let body =  SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()
    body.allowsResting = false
    body.mass = 80
    body.restitution = 0.1
    body.friction = 0.5
    body.rollingFriction = 0
    chassisNode.physicsBody = body
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(chassisNode)



    // add wheels
    let wheel0 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode0!)
    let wheel1 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode1!)
    let wheel2 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode2!)
    let wheel3 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode3!)
    // set physics
    vehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassisNode.physicsBody!,
                                wheels: [wheel1, wheel0, wheel3,wheel2 ])
    chassisNode.position = SCNVector3(0,-8,0)

    sceneView.scene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(vehicle)
}
```

Comment: Hey have solved your issues

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on a similar question, and realized that adding an `SCNFloor` did not necesarily create a good geometry to interact with as the PhysicsBody.

I recommend adding `sceneView.debugOptions = [.showPhysicsShapes]` so you can see the bounding boxes of the various physics objects interacting. In my case, I made the floor geometry a very wide, long, and thin box shape rather than trying to use the built-in "floor" geometry, which created only a tiny cube for collision interactions.

I've a bit of sample code in a macOS playground at [github.com/heckj/scenekit-physics-playground](https://github.com/heckj/scenekit-physics-playground) if you want to view and steal anything useful for debugging.